# How would I go about integrating Office 365 Sign-In with iOS

Tags: ios, authentication, office365, single-sign-on

How would I go about integrating office365 login with my iOS app?

With google-sign on, they have an SDK and it returns a token that the backend can verify it's the user.  Does MS offer anything similar?

Comment: You can try the [ADALiOS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc) library

Comment: Please see these posts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/ios-tutorial
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8a197f4e-1499-4c51-bcb4-667207cef14b/integrate-office-365-login-into-system?forum=appsforoffice